# Rails - convert ascii to characters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8, view, ascii

I'm using Rails 5 to show database content in a web browser.

In the db, all of the special characters are written in their ascii form. For instance, instead of an apostrophe, it's written as `&#39;`.

Thus, my view is showing the ascii code. Is there a way to convert them all to characters for the view?

Answer (score 4):

To transform ANY string containing HTML character entities, using Rails:

```
CGI.unescape_html "It doesn&#39;t look right" # => "It doesn't look right"
```

The `CGI` module is in the Ruby standard library and is required by Rails by default. If you want to do the same in a non-Rails project:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.unescape_html "It doesn&#39;t look right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example here's a simple Ruby solution if you want to define your own helper

```
39.chr # => "'"
'&#39;'.delete('&#;').to_i.chr # => "'"

module ApplicationHelper
  def ascii_to_char(ascii)
    ascii.delete('&#;').to_i.chr
  end
end

# in the views
ascii_to_char('&#39;') # => "'"
```

If what you really need is full HTML escaping see @forsym's answer

Answer (score 0):

Characters were fed through some "html entities" conversion before storing into the database.  Go back an fix that.